# Uso de maiúsculas ou minúsculas em UUID

Tags: independente-de-linguagem, uuid

Sei que o Standard define para o UUID que deve ser indicado com a presença de números e letras minúsculas.

O RFC-4122 diz que:

> *Each field is treated as an integer and has its value printed as a zero-filled hexadecimal digit string with the most significant digit first.  The hexadecimal values "a" through "f" are output as lower case characters and are case insensitive on input.*

No entanto e tratando-se de um valor em hexadecimal de 128bits com blocos separados por hifens, definir em minúsculas ou maiúsculas me parece ser irrelevante pelo facto que a definição é hexadecimal.

No entanto vejo por exemplo a Microsoft ou a Apple entre outros colocarem a string com maiúsculas "furando o Standard".

Estou a definir uma classe que trata identificadores únicos em PHP e entre estes utilizo o UUID versão 4.

Será mesmo irrelevante? Será que em determinadas implementações é importante ser minúscula ou maiúscula?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Um UUID (ou mesmo um GUID - uma de suas implementações) é essencialmente um número, entre `0` e `2^128` [-1]. Idealmente, ele deveria ser sempre tratado como um número, e principalmente comparado como um número. Converter um UUID pra string, só pra mostrar pro usuário de uma forma conveniente. Entretanto, quando se começa a *digitar* UUIDs a coisa começa a ficar complicada...

Eu não sei, historicamente falando, se o GUID surgiu primeiro e o UUID veio para padronizá-lo, ou se foi o contrário. Mas o fato é que, sim, a Microsoft não só usa letras maiúsculas num GUID como [as usa inconsistentemente](http://henbo.wordpress.com/2007/12/02/the-mystery-of-upper-case-and-lower-case-guid-values/). Isso provavelmente foi feito numa época em que não havia um padrão ou, como é típico da Microsoft, simplesmente ignorando os padrões. E depois mantido o que tinha, por compatibilidade. Desconheço a situação com a Apple.

Se seu sistema vai receber como entrada - do usuário ou de outro sistema - um UUID em formato texto, eu sugiro tratar de todas as variações possíveis (com tudo minúsculo, tudo maiúsculo, misturado, com ou sem o `{}` em volta, etc) e sempre tomando o cuidado com a codificação (*encoding*) do texto. A partir daí, use um número mesmo (se factível), e sempre faça qualquer comparação usando números, não texto. Se precisar fornecer um UUID como saída, use o formato padrão. Assim tem boas chances do consumidor desse UUID "entender" o formato - dado que se você usar algo não padronizado, isso pode ser rejeitado ou ainda pior, duplicado (vai que o sistema não checa isso, e salva o mesmo UUID em duas versões, uma com maiúsculas e outra com minúsculas...).

No fim das contas, a "importância" de se seguir o padrão é justamente para evitar erros de interoperabilidade. Sem saber se os sistemas que irão interagir com o seu "normalizam" os UUIDs antes de enviar/depois de receber, não dá pra garantir nada. O ideal é ver com cada sistema específico como é feito esse tratamento, mas na falta disso, seguir o padrão é o caminho com mais chance de sucesso.

Comment: obrigado pela resposta... A minha implementação garante a avaliação em minúsculas e maiúsculas... Pois como dito é um valor hexadecimal. A minha questão vai mais no sentido da indicação se a string  deva seguir ou não o padrão sendo que outros não o fazem...o que você em parte me responde. Estas empresas não o fariam sem um propósito... Que pode nada ter a ver com programação e ou standards... Entendes?

Comment: Eu entendo, mas a menos que alguém tenha mais informações que eu não conheça, creio que não existe razão nenhuma não. Só falta de padronização mesmo. i.e. Começou-se fazendo da forma X, padronizou-se que seria Y, mas agora tem esse monte de código e dados usando X que daria o maior trabalho pra adaptar, melhor deixar como está mesmo - já que faz pouca diferença... Pelo menos é assim que eu vejo.